# Closed addressing hash tables. How are they resized?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, hashmap, hashtable

Reading about [hopscotch hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing) and trying to understand how it can be code I realized that in linear probing hash table variants we need to have a recursive approach to resize as follows:

1. create a back up array of the existing buckets
2. allocate a new array of the requested capacity
3. go over the back up array and rehash each element to get
   the new position of the element in the new array and insert it in the
   new array
4. when done release the backup array

And the code structure would be like:

```
public V put(Object key, Object value) {  
   //code  
   //we need to resize)
   if(condition){  
       resize(2*keys.length);  
       return put(key, value);  
   }
   //other code
}  

private void resize(int newCapacity) {  
  //step 1 
  //step 2  
  //go over each element  
  for(Object key:oldKeys) {
    put(key, value);  
  }  
}
```

I don't like this structure as we recursively call put inside resize.
Is this the standard approach to resizing a hash table when using linear probing variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! Usually, in closed address hashing like hopscotch hashing, cuckoo hashing, or static perfect hashing where there's a chance that a rehash can fail, a single "rehash" step might have to sit in a loop trying to assign everything into a new table until it finds a way to do so that works.

You might want to consider having three methods - `put`, the externally visible function, `rehash`, an internal function, and `tryPut`, which tries to add an element, but might fail. You can then implement the functions like these, which are primarily for exposition and can definitely be optimized a bit:

```
public V put(Object key, Object value) {
    V oldValue = get(key);
    while (!tryPut(key, value)) {
        rehash();
    }
    return oldValue;
}

private void rehash() {
    increaseCapacity();

    boolean success;
    do {
       success = true;
       reallocateSpace();

       for (each old key/value pair) {
          if (!tryPut(key, value)) {
             success = false;
             break;
          }
       }
    } while (!success);
}

private boolean tryPut(Object key, Object value) {
   // Try adding the key/value pair using a
   // hashtable specific implementation, returning
   // true if it works and false otherwise.
}
```

There's no longer any risk of a weird recursion here, because `tryPut` never calls anything else.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting approach. I've never seen this approach. But if we have a high number of collisions isn't there the possibility to stuck in this loop doing `reallocateSpace` until we run out of memory?

Comment: @Cratylus I assume that on each iteration of the loop, the memory allocated in `reallocateSpace` would be reclaimed by the garbage collector, so there wouldn't be anything leaked. Also, in most systems where there's some rehashing allowed, the probability of a rehash failing is usually at most some constant, so on expectation only a constant number of rehashes would be necessary.

Comment: I wasn't talking about leaking. 1) But if you end up doing `new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` you'll end up with OOM if the heap space is not configured appropriately and 2) You can't insert anything to the table anymore and figuring this out from a resizing loop seems a bit strange IMHO. But this affects the closed addressing idea and not the answer which I find very enlightning

Comment: @Cratylus Oh, I see what you're saying. I've separated out the memory allocation into two steps - `increaseCapacity()`, which increases the size of the table that will be allocated, and `reallocateSpace()`, which gets new space of that size. The idea is that if a rehash fails, you reallocate a new array *of the same new size* and try again. You don't grow the size when a rehash fails.

Comment: But does this mean that we need to change to a different hash function? Because we usually do something like: `hash(key) % table.length`. So if the table is not resized and has the same length we'll get again the same set of collisions and never leave the loop. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Cratylus Yes, you definitely need to change the hash function. Cuckoo hashing definitely requires this, as does FKS perfect hash tables, and IIRC hopscotch hashing does as well. Usually, these data structures assume that you have a family of hash functions available so that if you need to rehash, you can change either the table size or the choice of hash function. This makes these systems a bit trickier to use than simple linear probing or chained hashing because you need a more intelligent hash function, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting. For hopscotch hashing the original paper states: `Moreover, unlike in cuckoo hashing, the chances of a successful displacement do not depend on the hash function h, so it can be a simple function that is easily shown to be close to universal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81579/discussion-between-templatetypedef-and-cratylus).

Comment: I am sorry. I was offline and did not see your message. If/when you have free time I would appreciate it to continue this over chat

Comment: @Cratylus I typed up a couple of paragraphs into chat. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them there!

Comment: I updated the chat! Your comments are very interesting actually

Comment: Updated chat with new data

Comment: I am preparing a testsuite. I'll let you know of the results in case you have time to give me a pointer